# Adding form in a ListView template

Tags: django, mixins, django-class-based-views

So, I built a listview which works fine. I was also able to add the form onto the same page as the listview. However, when I submit the form, the listview does not get updated with the recent form I submitted. I also get a strange error as well. I am not sure what went wrong.

views.py

```
class BlogListView(ListView, ModelFormMixin):
   model = Post
   context_object_name = 'blog_list'
   template_name= 'blog/blog_home.html'
   cats = Category.objects.all()
   ordering = ['-post_date']
   form_class = PostForm

   def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       self.object = None
       self.form = self.get_form(self.form_class)
       return ListView.get(self, request, *args, **kwargs)

   def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       self.object = None
       self.form = self.get_form(self.form_class)

       if self.form.is_valid():
           self.object = self.form.save()

       return self.get(request, *args, **kwargs)

   def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
       cat_menu = Category.objects.all()
       context = super(BlogListView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
       context["cat_menu"] = cat_menu
       context["form"] = self.form
       return context
```

urls.py

```
path('',BlogListView.as_view(),name='blog_home'),
```

forms.py

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = Post
       fields =('title', 'category', 'body')

       widgets = {
           'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
           'category': forms.Select(choices=choice_list,attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
           'body': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),

       }
```

blog_home.html:

```
            <div class="card-body">
                    <form action="" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            {{ form.media }}
                            {{ form|crispy }}
                            <input type="submit" value="Post"/>
                        </div>
                    </form>
            </div>
```

**Error when form method is "post"**:

IntegrityError at /
null value in column "author_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL: Failing row contains...

**Error when form method is "get"**:

GET /?csrfmiddlewaretoken

---

Edited:
models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
   id = models.UUIDField(
       primary_key = True,
       default = uuid.uuid4,
       editable = False)
   title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   author = models.ForeignKey(
       get_user_model(),
       on_delete=models.CASCADE,
   )
   ...
```

Comment: share your models.py with the author please. For the first error, i guess an author is mandatory in a Post. and your form has no author. if the author is the connected user, you can add a post.author = request.user

Comment: I just added the models.py.

Comment: @EricMartin, I tried adding post.author = request.user in blog_home.html and I am still getting the same error.